# A japanese styled Manga, where the MC gets reincarnated in another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

He becomes a merchant, and meets a girl selling flowers, and after buying one, he asks her if she would like to help him sell his wares. That's all I know so far.

Comment: This question is incredibly sparse. You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: For example, was it in black and white or colour? Was it an adult manga (with nudity/violence) or something more general? Did you read it personally or just hear about it? What did the guy look like? What did the girl look like? What kind of merchant was he? What was his name? How did he get reincarnated?

Comment: *Sekkaku Cheat wo Moratte Isekai ni Teni shita n dakara, Suki na You ni Ikitemitai (Since I received a cheat and was transported to another world, I'm going to live as I want*)? He spend most of the episodes making healing potions, selling them and using the money to hire prostitutes.

Comment: I think I just read this one not too long ago. I'll see if I can figure out what it's called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There wasn't much to go on, but the few details the poster gave match this manga: [*Itsudemo Jitaku Ni Kaerareru Ore Wa, Isekai De Gyoushounin O Hajimemashita by Hiiro Shimotsuki*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=170598)

[image: Cover pic of manga: Itsudemo Jitaku Ni Kaerareru Ore Wa, Isekai De Gyoushounin O Hajimemashita]

**Description and pic from Baka-Updates - Manga Division**

> "Won't I be able to get filthy rich if I use this skill?"
>
> Continually exploited at work, Amata Shirou quits his job and moves to his grandma's house. When he finds out that it's connected to another world, he comes up with a plan to set up a business selling Japanese goods.
>
> The story of a man getting rich using his skill that converts the currency of the other world to Japanese yen and so forth.

A man inherits the house of his grandmother after her passing. He finds a portal to another world in a hidden closet. He travels over and becomes a merchant. He meets the little girl on the cover pic in the other world. She's struggling selling flowers and he buys one from her. She's very grateful and thanks him, because she's trying to sell flowers to buy medicine for her sick mother. Feeling sorry for her he eventually buys all her flowers, telling her it's for decorations.

He meets her again later on and hires her to sell his items that he's bringing back from Japan. He has a skill that allows him to convert the money from that world into money from Japan and vice versa. He buys items in Japan and brings them back to the other world to sell. He then converts the other world's currency into Japanese currency and pockets the considerable profit.

Comment: Ooh. I looked at this one but didn't see anything about a flower selling girl.

Comment: Are we allowed to post direct links to online readers? I could show you, but I don't think it's allowed and I'd rather not be banned. Just google the name of it, you'll find plenty of websites where you can read it. Use adblockers. Some of them are suspect as far as malware, though. Also, she appears in the very first chapter, so you'll know if it's the one you're after or not.

Comment: Posting infringing links won't get you banned unless you keep doing it. That being said, don't do it (because it means extra work for others to flag it, have it removed and post you a warning comment)