# Manga where the main character is isekaied and becomes a merchant. He hires a flower girl to help in his shop

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

He meets the flower girl before he gets a shop building. The flower girl gives him advice, I think.
The MC also buys one of the flowers she's selling. The moment I remember is that, while he sells out, she didn't manage a single sale. Also, the girl's mom is sick.

Comment: What kind of shop was it? Just a flower shop, or was the MC selling other things as well?

Comment: Based on your acceptance, I have closed this as a duplicate. :) It's not a bad question (maybe a bit spare in details), just one we've answered before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [A japanese styled Manga, where the MC gets reincarnated in another world](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/251339/a-japanese-styled-manga-where-the-mc-gets-reincarnated-in-another-world), possibly [*Itsudemo Jitaku Ni Kaerareru Ore Wa, Isekai De Gyoushounin O Hajimemashita by Hiiro Shimotsuki*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=170598) or *I can always go home, started a peddler in a different world*

[image: Cover pic of manga: Itsudemo Jitaku Ni Kaerareru Ore Wa, Isekai De Gyoushounin O Hajimemashita]

One of Amata's early encounters is with the girl on the cover, who is selling flowers to get medicine for her sick mother. He buys her flowers

> "Won't I be able to get filthy rich if I use this skill?"
>
> Continually exploited at work, Amata Shirou quits his job and moves to his grandma's house. When he finds out that it's connected to another world, he comes up with a plan to set up a business selling Japanese goods.
>
> The story of a man getting rich using his skill that converts the currency of the other world to Japanese yen and so forth.